# Does STARTTLS also require Plaintext Authentication over TLS?

Tags: email, jakarta-mail

If a SSL SMTP server requires a STARTTLS command to be used (java mail property: `mail.smtp.starttls.required`), do we also need to enable Plaintext Authentication over TLS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "plaintext authentication over TLS".

If the server requires STARTTLS, a plain text (non-SSL) connection is made to the server, TLS (SSL) is started on the connection, and then authentication is done.  Authentication can use any authentication mechanisms supported by both client and server, including the PLAIN authentication mechanism.